# Reading a huge json file in R , issues

Tags: json, r

I am trying to read very huge json file using R , and I am using the RJSON library with this commend `json_data <- fromJSON(paste(readLines("myfile.json"), collapse=""))`

The problem is that I am getting this error message

```
Error in paste(readLines("myfile.json"), collapse = "") :
```

could not allocate memory (2383 Mb) in C function 'R_AllocStringBuffer'

Can anyone help me with this issue

Comment: R is not the best for really huge data files, as it loads all data into memory. You might need to process the file incrementally

Comment: To be more specific the R engine won't let you read a string as big as your file, and rjson is trying to read the whole thing at once.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but what I should do to read the json file.

Comment: Do you have a copy of the json file somewhere? Typically large json dumps get released in streamable jsonlines format, see `?stream_in` in the `jsonlite` package.

Answer (score 4):

Well, just sharing my experience about [read json file](https://class.coursera.org/dsscapstone-005/forum/thread?thread_id=12#comment-21). the progress of 
I am trying to read 52.8MB,19.7MB,1.3GB,93.9MB,158.5MB json files cost me 30minutes and finally auto resume R session, after that tried to apply parallel computing and would like to see the progress but failed.

https://github.com/hadley/plyr/issues/265

And then I tried to add the parameter *pagesize = 10000*, its work and more efficient then ever. Well, we only need read once and later save as RData/Rda/Rds format as by saveRDS.

```
> suppressPackageStartupMessages(library('BBmisc'))
> suppressAll(library('jsonlite'))
> suppressAll(library('plyr'))
> suppressAll(library('dplyr'))
> suppressAll(library('stringr'))
> suppressAll(library('doParallel'))
> 
> registerDoParallel(cores=16)
> 
> ## https://www.kaggle.com/c/yelp-recsys-2013/forums/t/4465/reading-json-files-with-r-how-to
> ## https://class.coursera.org/dsscapstone-005/forum/thread?thread_id=12
> fnames <- c('business','checkin','review','tip','user')
> jfile <- paste0(getwd(),'/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset/yelp_academic_dataset_',fnames,'.json')
> dat <- llply(as.list(jfile), function(x) stream_in(file(x),pagesize = 10000),.parallel=TRUE)
> dat
list()
> jfile
[1] "/home/ryoeng/Coursera-Data-Science-Capstone/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset/yelp_academic_dataset_business.json"
[2] "/home/ryoeng/Coursera-Data-Science-Capstone/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset/yelp_academic_dataset_checkin.json" 
[3] "/home/ryoeng/Coursera-Data-Science-Capstone/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset/yelp_academic_dataset_review.json"  
[4] "/home/ryoeng/Coursera-Data-Science-Capstone/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset/yelp_academic_dataset_tip.json"     
[5] "/home/ryoeng/Coursera-Data-Science-Capstone/yelp_dataset_challenge_academic_dataset/yelp_academic_dataset_user.json"    
> dat <- llply(as.list(jfile), function(x) stream_in(file(x),pagesize = 10000),.progress='=')
opening file input connection.
 Imported 61184 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
closing file input connection.
opening file input connection.
 Imported 45166 records. Simplifying into dataframe...
closing file input connection.
opening file input connection.
 Found 470000 records...
```

Answer (score 2):

I got the same problem while working with huge datasets in R.I had used jsonlite package in R for reading json in R.I had used the following code to read json in R:

```
library(jsonlite)
get_tweets <- stream_in(file("tweets.json"),pagesize = 10000)
```

here tweets.json is the my file name and the location where it exists,pagesize represents how many number of lines it reads in one iteration.Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the above solutions all caused R to terminate or worse.

This solution worked for me, with the same data set:

```
library(jsonlite)
file_name <- 'C:/Users/Downloads/yelp_dataset/yelp_dataset~/dataset/business.JSON'
business<-jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(readLines(file_name, n=100000)),verbose=F)
```

Took about 15 minutes