# Batch processing a 30GB json file in R

Tags: r, json, csv, bigdata

I have a large (30GB) json file of tweets I'd like to parse and conduct some text analysis with in R. Tweets were acquired using the filter_stream function from the twitteR package about 2 years ago. Here is a sample (pretty standard): https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecrfo3etk2ingcm/WomensMarch2018.json?dl=0.

My computer grinds to a halt anytime I attempt the following:

```
library(streamR)
mydata <- parseTweets("BigData.json", simplify = TRUE)
```

I know I need to batch process the file, else move to a cloud server with tons of RAM, but I don't know how to do either. Can anyone help?

Edit: I tried this solution ([Reading a huge json file in R , issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688946/reading-a-huge-json-file-in-r-issues)), but get the following error:

```
Error: lexical error: invalid char in json text.
          _at":"Wed Jul 21 12:54:05 +{"created_at":"Sat Jan 21 17:18:2
                     (right here) ------^
```

Comment: Did you try `jsonlite` to read the json file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a huge json file in R , issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688946/reading-a-huge-json-file-in-r-issues)

Comment: Please stick to the internationally agreed SI units system - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units Please use **B** for **bytes** and **b** for **bits**, so one megabyte is 1MB, one gigabyte is 1GB (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabyte), one gigabit is 1Gb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit), and if you have to refer to a milllibit for some reason that would be 1mb. Thank you.

Comment: I tried the solution @Bulat indicated, but get an error: added edit above. Thank you!