# .json file is too large to be opened in R with rjson

Tags: r, json, size

I have a 5.1 GB json file that I would like to read in R using rjson. I want afterwards to construct a dataframe from it, however it won't load because the size is too large.

Is there any way to work around it?

Thank you for your help =)

Comment: Nina, you are welcome to Stackoverflow community; here people will voluntarily help you and give you some advise. Next time you will ask a question, make sure that you provide us with some sample data (or ```dput()```). It has advantages both for you and community - it's faster for you to receive an answer and easier for us to find the solution (and practice our coding skills!).

Comment: @k1rgas , thank you for your kind answer, I will make sure to incorporate your advice in all of my future questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nina, I would recommend you using `jsonlite` package instead of `rjson`.

```
library(jsonlite)
your_json <- "your_path.json"
unpacked_json <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(readLines(your_json, n=100000)),verbose=F)
```

Here you limit the page size to let IDE correctly read your JSON file. For more information I would also recommend you to make some research on this topic:

1. https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-read-large-json-file-in-r/13486
2. [Reading a huge json file in R , issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29688946/reading-a-huge-json-file-in-r-issues)

I know for sure that it is sometimes really hard to cope with documentation (and as all other human beings we are lazy); and I don't like to read doc-n myself, but I highly recommend you to make yourself familiar with `jsonlite` documentation and vignettes. Here's the CRAN link: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/index.html

Comment: thank you so much for your super-fast answer! thank you also for the research links, I will go and educate myself some more first!